# How to setup the connectionString when hosting a .net core appl on IIS, Windows 10?

Tags: sql-server, iis

I was following this [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Z1Lg7ssD8I) on how to host an Asp.net Core application on *IIS*, Windows 10. Which worked fine. Now I tried to build on top of that by adding a **connectionString** to a sql server instance on my local computer.

when running the application using visual studio, it working fine. However, when I publish that to a folder and then run it using *IIS*, it's throwing an error.

This is my connection:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "MembersDatabase": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MembersDb;Integrated Security=True"
 }
```

And this is how I'm accessing it:

```
services.AddDbContext<MembersContext>
                (options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MembersDatabase"))
            );
```

Is there a particular way of setting up the **connectionstring**? This is my first time doing this.

## EDIT

This is not a production setup. I'll clone the real application on this laptop. After I've successfully completed the setup, this laptop will be used to demo the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the problem,

1. I enabled mix authentication for the sql server.
2. Create a user
3. Give the appropriate credentials to the user (read/write)

the connection string looks like this now.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "MembersDatabase": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MembersDb;User Id=test_user;Password=P@ssword123;"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say exactly, especially since you didn't post the actual error you're getting. However, my best guess is that you're not customizing the connection string for your deployment environment.

The way you're doing it currently relies on LocalDb, which only works/exists within the IDE of Visual Studio. When deploying to IIS, you're going to need a real database instance and real database credentials.

Setting up a database server is far beyond the scope of what can reasonably be covered here, so if you need help there, you'll need to do some research on your own. Once you've got an actual instance and database, then it's time to customize your connection string for your deployment environment.

Now, there's multiple way you can go here. In general, you want to provide a piece of config that will override what's being set in your development environment/by default. That could be an environment-specific JSON file like `appsettings.Production.json`, an environment variable (which you'd set either manually on the target server or via your CI/CD pipeline), or even an external source such as Azure Key Vault. I will say that since connection strings usually contain information that should be kept secret (passwords), you should avoid JSON and other file-based config options, as those are not encrypted and generally committed to your source control. Environment variables, Azure Key Vault, etc. should be your goto solution here.

Anyways, the config works literally on an override basis, so you just need to mimic the structure present in your `appsettings.json`. For config sources that don't allow hierarchical structures like JSON, then, you can use colons (`:`) to separate the items in the tree: `ConnectionStrings:MembersDatabase` as the config key. For example, as an environment variable, that would be the variable name.

Comment: to start with, thank you so much for answering. As you may have noticed, I'm really novice on setting up IIS. That said, this is not for production purposes. I was just asked to set up the angular app, .net core app, and a sql server on a laptop using IIS. This is just for demo purpose. I've made a lot of progress with regards to .NET CORE and angular. The `connectonstring` string is the part that's making my life miserable.

Comment: patt, so what you mean is that I should add another file called `appsettings.production.json` and IIS will be able to pick it up? So, is it a convention?

Comment: Given OP's self answer, this has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core, it's all about SQL Server and user rights, which you as well said, out of scope as nothing of that is available in the question.